# Serial print message results in gibberish

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming

I'm trying to print messages to the serial monitor, and all I get is some unreadable format.

Looping `Serial.println("Wait...!");` gives me the following results:

```
ö’ö’ƒÕ•¬­ƒ´¼Õƒö­“ƒ²ƒƒƒ¬‘¼¬Õ”’­­“ƒ¬•
```

Why is it unreadable, and how do I make it print a readable format?

Comment: By printing at the same baud rate that you are reading at?

Comment: Please show the code that initializes the Serial communication (`Serial.begin(...)`). Then show the settings of your serial monitor. I think just doing that should give you the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "weird" result usualy happens when you select then wrong baud rate or a different one then the one you beginned the serial communication with in the program. Thus by using `Serial.begin(9600);`, you have to make sure that the serial monitor is actually set to a baud rate of 9600.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea what baud rate is, but I figured it out with your answer